# Error message on google console during review apk "This releaese is not compliant with the Google Play 64 bit requirement"

Tags: android, apk, appcelerator, google-play-console, hybrid

The following APKs OR App bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code:2.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing formate to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this info. And please say what exactly you are asking for

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html